# Category Toolbar Showing Incorrect Count and Paging Not Working

Tags: layered-navigation, category-products, magento2.3.3, toolbar

I've got a problem with a live site where the toolbar is showing the incorrect product count, not changing sort direction or filter nor is it changing the product on pagination change.

You can see it here - [Tuckers Butchers Poultry](https://www.tuckersbutchers.com/poultry.html)

It is showing 1-33 of 33 products where the filter count is set to 20

If you click page 2 at the bottom of the page, it changes to "21-53 of 33" but the shown products remain the same.

If you choose price "descending" , again, the page refreshes but the products remain the same.

I have a development site running the same code base that works fine, both are running Magento 2.3.3

The only difference is the live site has docroot set to /pub/ and I wondered if anyone else has seen this happen??

Oddly, the toolbar works ok in Search results.

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm having similar issues. Can you tell me which block was re-written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of tracking this down, I discovered it was a third part Rich Snippets module that had been upgraded recently.

The company concerned have re-written their Block code over night and it's working now.

Comment: can you share your answer

Comment: Could you please share exact solution so that would be appreciated?

Comment: It was being caused by a bug in a third party Rich Snippets module developed by BSS Commerce but they fixed it 2 years ago.

I didn't have to fix anything, their developers did it and I just upgraded.

Sorry I can't help further.